# print content of files in remote server using: python, ssh, subprocess, find -print0

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I'm Trying to connect to a remote server using python subprocess and ssh, list the files in a directory using 'find . -print0' and print out the content of each file line by line avoiding memory issues. any ideas guys?

Comment: It might be a better idea to use a module like pexpect.

Answer (score 1):

I would sugest bash, but if you really want to stick with python.
http://www.lag.net/paramiko/ is a client for ssh. From that, if you know ssh, is just executing some commands from the other side.

Comment: I have to use python subprocess.Popen :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have a look to [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.1/index.html), it is implemented in Python and is aware of managing big streams between remote host and asker.

EDIT :

to print out the content of your files, try this :

```
find . -exec cat {} \;
```

then, you'll have to send it with ssh to your remote host

```
ssh user@host 'find . -exec cat {} \;'
```

then, call this with a [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) call